# XSLT - Why is changing the node context not working?

Tags: xslt

## XSLT - Why is changing the node context not working?

**My source XML document**

I have a given source XML document that consists of one `<definition>` and some `<override>` elements. Each `<variable>` element within the `<definition>` element corresponds to exactly one `<assignment>` element within an `<override>` element. This 1:1 relationship is established by the content (ID) of their `<name>` element.

This is a sample of my source XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sample>
  <definition>
    <variable>
      <name>object01_ID_138368350261919620</name>
      <value>NUL</value>
    </variable>  
    <variable>
      <name>param01_ID_138368350261919621</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>param02_ID_138368350261919622</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </variable>
  </definition>
  <override>
    <assignment>
      <name>object01_ID_138368350261919620</name>
      <path>module01/object01</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>param01_ID_138368350261919621</name>
      <path>module01/object01/param01</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>param02_ID_138368350261919622</name>
      <path>module01/object01/param02</path>
    </assignment>
  </override>
</sample>
```

**My target XML document**

Depending on the pattern of the content of the `<path>` elements, within the `<assignment>` elements in an `<override>` element, I like to add a new `<assignment>` element. An `<assignment>` element is the leading information. Therefore always at first, I have to create a new `<assignment>` element with its `<path>` and `<name>` content. After that, I have to create a corresponding `<variable>` element with the same `<name>` content and a specific `<value>` content.

This is a sample (adding *param03*) of my target XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sample>
  <definition>
    <variable>
      <name>param00_ID_138368350261919620</name>
      <value>NUL</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>param01_ID_138368350261919621</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>param02_ID_138368350261919622</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>Param03_ID_138368350261919623</name>
      <value>1000</value>
    </variable>
  </definition>
  <override>
    <assignment>
      <name>param00_ID_138368350261919620</name>
      <path>module01/object01</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>param01_ID_138368350261919621</name>
      <path>module01/object01/param01</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>param02_ID_138368350261919622</name>
      <path>module01/object01/param02</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>Param03_ID_138368350261919623</name>
      <xpath>module01/object01/param03</xpath>
    </assignment>
  </override>
</sample>
```

**My XSLT document**

For identity transformation, I have choosen to use the fine-grained control identity rule, recommended by [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev). With the code below *"processing variable assignment"*, I create a new `<assignment>` element with its specific `<path>` and `<name>` content. After that, with the code below *"processing variable definition"* I like to change the node context to the `<definition>` element and add on last position a new `<variable>` element with the corresponding `<name>` content and a specific `<value>` content.

This is my XSLT document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="fo xs fn">
  <!--
  global declarations ==========================================================
  -->
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!-- randomid here is just a fake for sake of simplification -->
  <xsl:variable name="randomid" select="138368350261919623"/>
  <!--
  template for identity ==========================================================
  -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--
  template for variable assignment ===============================================
  -->
  <xsl:template name="variable_assignment">
    <xsl:param name="value_node_name"/>
    <xsl:param name="value_node_path"/>
    <xsl:message select="'processing: variable assignment'"/>
    <xsl:message select="concat('applying name: ', $value_node_name)"/>
    <xsl:message select="concat('applying path: ', $value_node_path)"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <assignment>
      <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value_node_name"/>
      </name>
      <xpath>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value_node_path"/>
      </xpath>
    </assignment>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--
    template for processing param03 =============================================
  -->
  <xsl:template match="/sample/override[not(assignment
              /path[matches(text(), '.*/object01/param03$')])]
              /assignment[path[matches(text(), '.*/object01$')]]">
    <!-- setting params -->
    <xsl:param name="value_node_name_target">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Param03_ID', '_', $randomid)"/>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="value_node_path_target">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(./path, '/param03')"/>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="value_node_value_target" select="'1000'"/>
    <!-- processing variable assignment -->
    <xsl:call-template name="variable_assignment">
      <xsl:with-param name="value_node_name" select="$value_node_name_target"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="value_node_path" select="$value_node_path_target"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <!-- processing variable definition -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/sample/definition/*[position()=last()]">
        <xsl:message select="'processing: variable definition'"/>
      <xsl:message select="concat('Here we are: ', .)"/>
      <xsl:message select="concat('applying name: ', $value_node_name_target)"/>
      <xsl:message select="concat('applying value: ', $value_node_value_target)"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      <variable>
        <name>
          <xsl:value-of select="$value_node_name_target"/>
        </name>
        <value>
          <xsl:value-of select="$value_node_value_target"/>
        </value>
      </variable>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My wrong resulting XML document**

The problems I got:

1. The node context becomes not changed as intended by using `<xsl:for-each select="/sample/definition/*[position()=last()]">`. The new `<variable>` element becomes added at last position into the `<override>` element, instead into the `<definition>` element, as intended.
2. Additionally the last `<variable>` element from `<definition>` element becomes copied into the `<override>` element.

This is my wrong XML document, I got after transformation as described above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sample>
  <definition>
    <variable>
      <name>object01_ID_138368350261919620</name>
      <value>NUL</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>param01_ID_138368350261919621</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>param02_ID_138368350261919622</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </variable>
  </definition>
  <override>
    <assignment>
      <name>object01_ID_138368350261919620</name>
      <path>module01/object01</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>param01_ID_138368350261919621</name>
      <path>module01/object01/param01</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>param02_ID_138368350261919622</name>
      <path>module01/object01/param02</path>
    </assignment>
    <assignment>
      <name>Param03_ID_138368350261919623</name>
      <xpath>module01/object01/param03</xpath>
    </assignment>
    <variable>
      <name>param02_ID_138368350261919622</name>
      <value>100</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>Param03_ID_138368350261919623</name>
      <value>1000</value>
    </variable>
  </override>
</sample>
```

**The help I need**

I really would appreciate if somebody of you could advice me, in which way I would have to adapt my XSLT document in order to change the node context as described. (All code listed above is created and tested with Saxon HE 9.5).

Many thanks.

Regarding your question, that's my current solution for creating a random ID (instead of the fake for sake of simplification):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
    xmlns:math="java:java.lang.Math" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn math">

    <xsl:variable name="baseid" 
                  select='format-number((((math:random() * 
                      10000000000000) mod 10000000000000) + 
                      10000000000000), "#")'/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This solution requires *Saxon PE* because of applying `xmlns:math="java:java.lang.Math"`. It works robust and fast but I'm not completely statisfied with it. The ID's that are existing in the source XML document are incremented by 1. Therefore I like to write a solution, that selects that ID of the existing ID's with the highest value, takes that as basis value and creates further ID's basded on that ID by incrementing them each witht 1. Such a solution would take advantage of the existing ID's of the source XML document, looks straightforward and additionally run's with a *Saxon HE* license. That task is still on my todo list.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably missing something here, because it seems to me this could be much simpler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>


<!-- fakes for sake of simplification -->
<xsl:variable name="randomid" select="'138368350261919623'"/>
<xsl:variable name="next_variable_value" select="1000"/>


<xsl:template match="/sample"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="definition"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="override"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="definition"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="variable">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <variable>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Param03_ID_', $randomid)"/>
            </name>
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="$next_variable_value"/>
            </value>
        </variable>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="override"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="assignment">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <assignment>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Param03_ID_', $randomid)"/>
            </name>
            <xpath>module01/object01/param03</xpath>
        </assignment>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, the more interesting part is how the "fakes for sake of simplification" will be produced.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I tested your transformation style and it works perfectly as long as I apply it in `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" ...>`. As soon as I try to apply it in `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" ...>`, the resulting XML is much the same than the wrong resulting XML I listed above. I'm sorry, I didn't mention explicitly that I like to use **XSLT version 2.0**. Do you know how does the code has to look like to run in `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" ...>`?

Comment: That's my current solution for creating a random ID:

    <xsl:stylesheet 
        version="2.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
        xmlns:math="java:java.lang.Math" 
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn math">

        <xsl:variable name="baseid" 
                      select='format-number((((math:random() * 
                          10000000000000) mod 10000000000000) + 
                          10000000000000), "#")'/>
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I am afraid I cannot reproduce your issue; I am getting exactly the same result after changing the stylesheet version to "2.0". Tested on Saxon 8.9.

Comment: Mea culpa! You are absolutely right! I did the mistake. Your solution works for XSL version 2.0 as well as for version 1.0. Excellent job! Thank you very much.